# Save approximation results outside of R

Tags: r, save, workflow

I need to run very time-consuming approximation for posterior distribution. Thus, I desire to save the parameters' samples outside of R for future analysis.

My samples are in the form of matrices and vectors (each element of which is result from one simulation). Is there a way to save these matrices and vectors to file?

Relatedly, could you please comment on efficient workflow for these time consuming approximations? I find myself highlighting and running long codes repeatedly -- surely there is a better way to load, run, then save analyses?

Many thanks!

Comment: You question is a little unspecific. Have you read `?saveRDS`?

Comment: saveRDS saves a single object, right? Is there a way to save all of my matrices and vectors of results in one file? I want to be able to open this "file" and all of those matrices and vectors will be loaded into R to analyze (traceplots, quantile, etc.)

Comment: Read the help page. It mentions alternatives, which save several objects or even the whole workspace.

Answer (score 1):

Ahn has already provided you with your first answer.

```
saveRDS(obj, "obj.rds")
obj <- readRDS("obj.rds")
```

Those commands present the basis for serialization in R.

As Roland mentioned, you can also save and load your entire workspace in the same manner:

```
save.image("my_workspace.RData")
load("my_workspace.RData")
```

With respect to workflow. I highly recommend that you get used to packaging EVERYTHING that you do in R. It's significantly more productive to take the extra step and package your work.

When you create a package skeleton, typically, data is stored in `/extdata/data/obj.rds` and then accessed after package load via:

```
obj <- readRDS(paste(path.package('package_name'),"/data/obj.rds"))
# R < 3.0.0 it's .path.package, not path.package
```

Generally, I store all of my analysis as functions. So then it's just a matter of running that function to get the desired results.

For example:

```
#' My Analysis Function
#' 
#' This function does x, y, and z. 
#' 
#' @param obj The name of the object...
#' @export your_analysis_fun

your_analysis_fun <- function(obj="name") {
 obj <- readRDS(paste(path.package('package_name'),"/data/",obj,".rds"))
 # the things you usually copy paste go here
 # ...
 return(results)
}
```

Documenting your code is also helpful, I've included a brief example of that above (Roxygen2). If you use RStudio, it's a simple matter of mashing Ctrl + Shift + B to build and reload your package and then run your function again as you make changes. They've done a great job of making the workflow paradigm for packages worthwhile. Recommend using git, too.

I cannot stress the importance of documenting your code enough. Coming back to a complicated analysis a year later is like smacking yourself in the face with a baseball bat if you haven't done your due diligence in writing documentation. Not to mention trying to pick up where someone else left off.

Comment: I used `save` to store all of my matrices and vectors. What is the difference between `save, saveRDS, save.image`? Also, what do you mean by "packaging" ? These may be basic questions, so if you could provide a link, I can read up myself too. Thanks for the point about using function!

Comment: It's a long but worthwhile read: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html saveRDS saves an object. save, saves a workspace, save.image is just a wrapper for save for your entire workspace.